# Tbody not appearing on full page when height given in '%'

Tags: html, css, html-table

Hi I am creating a header fixed table. I want to make a table in which tbody will expand with screen size so I want to give height in percentage `%` but it is not working properly . But When I give in pixel it works. Here is link of [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7293/) . Where I am trying to give `tbody` height in `%`.

```css
      table {
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
        }

        thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

        tr:after {
            content: ' ';
            display: block;
            visibility: hidden;
            clear: both;
        }

        thead th {
            height: 30px;

            /*text-align: left;*/
        }

        tbody {
            height: 125px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        thead {
            /* fallback */
        }


        tbody td, thead th {
            width: 19.2%;
            float: left;
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

Comment: You are using  `tbody { height: 125px; overflow-y: auto;}` so table doesn't take full height.

Comment: @LokeshGupta yes I said When I replace height :125px ; with 100% height dosen't show anything.

Comment: use `height:100vh;` in table  i think it will work

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update css part

```
tbody {
  height: 100vh; /*add this */
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Working fiddle

**[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ocs69ss5/2/)**

```css
thead,
tbody,
tr,
td,
th {
  display: block;
}

tr:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

thead th {
  height: 30px;
  /*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
  /* fallback */
}

tbody td,
thead th {
  width: 19.2%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Make</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
      <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: After using this table head not remain fixed . I want a table head fixed.

Comment: thank you @Lokesh Gupta.  Thats what I was looking for. thank you. And upvote question if possible .

Answer (score 0):

You can't use tbody as 100% height because there is "nothing in" and will be blank, you need to add 100% height to content itself which is td.
If you want tbody to be fixed you can do that example: 125px height are 125 usable pixels and all content will be scrollable in 125px.
Change tbody and add tbody tr td as below.

```
tbody  {  
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

and add

```
tbody tr td  {  
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Comment: After using this table head not remain fixed . I want a table head fixed.